# How to negate square brackets in MySQL regex

Tags: mysql, regex, database, regex-negation

I am trying to match a variable name that does not contain square brackets using MySQL regexp. However when I write something includes:

```
[^[]]
```

MySQL does not execute the matching and returns OK in the Message panel, which mean the query has not been executed.

Question: How to negate square brackets in MySQL?

**EDIT:**

I use MysQL server 8.0.16 and MySQL workbench 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL5.x only allows `]` in a character class if it is the *first* character in the class (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)). So you need to rework your character class as `[^][]`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE vars (varname VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO vars VALUES
('hello world'),
('hello [world'),
('hello world]'),
('hello [world]');
SELECT varname, varname RLIKE '^[^][]+$' AS `match`
FROM vars
```

Output:

```
varname         match
hello world     1
hello [world    0
hello world]    0
hello [world]   0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSHzsq2N8kPpzvQgWqwKep/0)

MySQL 8+ uses a different regex engine (thanks @WiktorStribiżew), so the regex needs to be modified to `[^]\\[]` in that case (without escaping the `[`, MySQL complains about an "unclosed bracket expression"). This form of the regex also works fine in MySQL 5.7.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSHzsq2N8kPpzvQgWqwKep/1)

Comment: Good answer, different behaviour seems worthy of a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com) (I haven't found an existing one however). Technically the manual says `]` directly after the starting `[` which taken literally means `[^][]` isn't really within the scope of supported n the manual.

Comment: @danblack you're probably right. IMO the regex `^[^][]+$` should work, as the `^` isn't really a character in the class. MySQL 8 complains about an "unclosed bracket expression"

Comment: @danblack Unfortunately I can't report a bug without an Oracle account.

Comment: `[^][]` is not a legal character class in ICU regex because the square brackets are used to form character class unions/intersections and should be escaped inside a character class. For some reason, ICU developers did not add the "smart placing" algorithm for these chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so do you think MySQL 5.7 processing that class properly is actually incorrect behaviour? It seems to be the only viable way of doing it in MySQL 5.7; using `^[^\\]\\[]+$` or `^[^\\[\\]]+$` doesn't match any of the strings.

Comment: @Nick MySQL 5.7 POSIX compliant regex engine shows correct POSIX regex behavior. I added a comment because of *For some reason this doesn't work in MySQL 8+* in your answer. It is because the regex engines differ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the clarification. I misunderstood your prior comment.

Comment: @danblack let me know what you hear back. Wiktor is suggesting that it's because they changed the regex engine in MySQL 8

Comment: Sure, we'll let the MySQL developers think about it and if maintaining 5.7 compatibility or ICU regex is more important in this manner.

Comment: @Nick In your `[^]\\[]` Do you notice that you used `\\[` but not `\\]` ?? Plz clarify if this is a typo or it should be like this

Comment: @user9371654 yes it's intentional. The MySQL5.7 regex engine insists that `]` is the first character in the class (excluding the `^` for negation) and preceding it with `\\\` violates that. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSHzsq2N8kPpzvQgWqwKep/3

Comment: @Nick plz check my edit. I use MySQL 8+. I am confused. Can you write the regex to say not `]` and not `[`. I tried `[^][]` but it is not accepted. And in you answer, in the code you use `[^][]` but later you say `[^]\\[]`. so which one is correct?

Comment: @user9371654 as I said in the answer, in 8+ you need to use `[^]\\[]`. See my second demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSHzsq2N8kPpzvQgWqwKep/1

Comment: @user9371654 I don't know if it is a bug. We'll have to wait to hear back from danblack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193261/discussion-between-user9371654-and-nick).

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT` in your query:

Look at this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name NOT REGEXP  "[\\[\\]]"
```

What this part of Query

```
REGEXP  "[\\[\\]]"
```

is saying, select all rows which contain `[` and `]`.

But, using not, actually you are saying select all rows which not contain `[` or `]`;

Comment: This won't work in MySQL 5.7 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSHzsq2N8kPpzvQgWqwKep/2

Comment: This small piece is part of a bigger query and I can not make it `not regexp`.